# How to overriding CoreBundle/Checkout?

Tags: sylius

Using Sylius, I created a own bundle, his name space: src/Acme/ShopBundle.
How to Override sylius service like checkout ? Can you give me a little suggestion for beginning ? a workflow ?

Merci beaucoup !

Comment: May be sylius is too hard to eat as my first symfony cookie ? any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html).

in your case the process method will look something like this

```
public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $definition = $container->getDefinition('sylius.checkout_scenario');
    $definition->setClass('Acme\ShopBundle\Process\YourShhopScenario');
}
```

After that check this [link](http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/SyliusFlowBundle/installation.html#creating-scenario) to see how to defined your checkout steps. Also you can see the sylius scenario class: `Sylius\Bundle\CoreBundle\Checkout\CheckoutProcessScenario` (class namespace)